# MarkLogic not starting on AWS, failing with DynamoDB error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, marklogic

I have a 3 node MarkLogic cluster using CloudFormation Template. The setup ran fine with the provided configuration but the MarkLogic server is not coming up. I checked by logging into the EC2 instance and i saw the service has not started. So i tried to run it manually an di got the below error.

MarkLogic version is 11.0.2.

```
[root@ip-100-202-30-37 etc]# service MarkLogic start
Set configuration: JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64"
Set configuration: MARKLOGIC_MDB_TYPE="ddb"
Set configuration: AWS_REGION="us-east-1"
Set configuration: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
Set configuration: MARKLOGIC_ZONE="us-east-1c"
Set configuration: MARKLOGIC_HOSTNAME="ip-100-202-30-37.ec2.internal"
Initialize Configuration.
AWS Region: us-east-1, ZONE: us-east-1c. INSTANCE: i-0sdeftghyuj908yt
Configured node name. MARKLOGIC_NODE_NAME: NodeC#
Set configuration: MARKLOGIC_MDB_TYPE="ddb"
Managed cluster initialization
Localized name pattern to NodeC-us-east-1c#
No
MDB found: ml-cluster-v11-MarkLogicDDBTable-2DRFTGHU67OKL   - aborting
```

I also verified the master cluster node and it is correct in CFT. Also the DDB table it complains about got created while running the CFT but it is empty. Not able understand the reason.